# How to save data files after failing to boot Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual boot laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, live-usb

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot laptop; + Win10), after some days got into a login screen loop. When I tried to fix it with various methods, I ended up with black screen while booting. Now it seems the only option is to reinstall Ubuntu from a bootable usb. From what I read, I should be able to access my files (I need to back them up) from the the usb when I choose the option "try ubuntu", but in reality I get an empty file system. Also, when I try to install, the only options I get is to either erase ubuntu and reinstall or erase the disc and reinstall. Either way I will lose my data. Is there a way to save the data now?

[image: my partitions]

Comment: If you can launch the software on the usb, then one can mount any partition (use Gparted or Disks). Then connect another USB-disc and copy the contents to be saved to the second USB.

Comment: @Bernard Decock yes, thank you. This helped, I will now see if I can recover the system without reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now it seems the only option is to reinstall Ubuntu from a bootable usb.

You also have these 2 options.

1. boot from a live session/usb.
2. use emergency mode from grub.

You need to mount your user disk after that and you can then navigate to your personal data.

> I need to back them up

Sure but you already made one before you upgraded so use that one. Otherwise you can the live session usb (is easier than grub) to do that.

> Also, when I try to install, the only options I get is to either erase ubuntu and reinstall or erase the disc and reinstall.

You always also get an option "something else" and you can there mount user disks without formatting.

Comment: I had tried using emergency mode or boot older kernel but without success. I will ask another question to see if reinstall is the best option now after I managed to backup the data.